# Description error in Eclipse IDE for BlackBerry app generation

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java

I am creating a HelloWorld program in Eclipse IDE for BlackBerry.
But I am getting following error :
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
InvalidRegex: Pattern value '([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character range. Write '-'.' at column '{2}'. BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml   /HelloWorld Unknown XML Problem

I tried uninstalling jdk 7.0 and instaling jdk 6.0 and trying, as suggested by few ppl.
But it didnt work for me. Can anyone please provide a solution for this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Can be fixed  by switching Eclipse default JRE from 7 to 6. 
in Window->Preferences->Java

Or you can try by deleting the BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml and then it got created again.

If that doesn't help
The problem is with Java 1.7, which the plugin doesn't currently support. You will need to use Java 1.6 32bit for development with the Eclipse plugin.

First uninstall jdk7. Then download and install jdk6.

Next time do some research before asking. The solution was rigth there. You will become a better programmer if you try and read before waiting for someone's answer